# asyncawait module (node) yields unusable stack traces

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stack-trace, bluebird

I am having a problem with using the async/await implementation for node.js (*https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait*).

In the documentation it says that **"will include a useable stack trace"**. But it does not do so for me. So I think I am doing it wrong..but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

To demonstrate I will compare the stacktrace of a "vanilla" bluebird example with the corresponding stacktrace of the corresponding asyncawait code (asyncawait uses bluebird internally so I think it's fair).

First the bluebird code without asyncawait:

```
var funcB = function() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    throw new Error("some err");
  })
};

var funcA = function() {
  return funcB();
};

gulp.task("aa",function(cb) {
  funcA().then(function() {
    cb();
  });
});
```

The stacktrace yields the information "funcA -> funcB -> exception" at first glace. Does not get any better!

```
Error: Error: some err
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
From previous event:
    at funcB (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\tmp\tsreq\app\gulpfile.js:156:30)
    at funcA (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\tmp\tsreq\app\gulpfile.js:161:12)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\tmp\tsreq\app\gulpfile.js:164:5)
    at module.exports (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Now the corresponding asyncawait code:

```
var funcB = async(function() {
  throw new Error("some err");
});

var funcA = async(function () {
  await(funcB());
});

gulp.task("aa", function(cb) {
  funcA().then(function() {
    cb();
  });
});
```

In the stacktrace I only see the exception. No "funcA", no "funcB".

For this simple program this is sufficient. *But* I can't use it for other more complex stuff, considering how important stacktraces actually are..

```
Possibly unhandled Error: Error: some err
    at catchBlock (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\fiberManager.js:51:25)
    at runInFiber (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\fiberManager.js:29:9)
From previous event:
    at new Promise (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\asyncawait\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:84:37)
    at defer (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\defer.js:6:19)
    at nonIterable (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\makeAsyncFunc.js:86:28)
    at f0 (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\asyncawait\src\async\makeAsyncFunc.js:119:23)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\tmp\tsreq\app\gulpfile.js:162:5)
    at module.exports (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\projects\JSBuildHelper\JSBuildHelper\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
    at C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Am I doing it wrong or is this really a limitition that I cannot remove?

Comment: You're not supposed to get `funcA/B` in any promise compliant context. `.then` is executed asynchronously, so the initial function is never in stack. Unless you extend your own logging (printing some context-related info) you can't really match which call actually started the async operation

Comment: Why does it print funcA/B in the first case though? Both cases involve promise compliant contextes, as you mention.